# Recursively move folders/files within subfolders to its parent

Tags: powershell, directory, move, parent, relative-path

I have a high level folder (call it 'level 0'), which contains a hundred or so subfolders ('level 1'), and within those subfolders consist of lower level subfolders and files ('level 2'). I need to dynamically move every file and folder from 'level 2' to its level 1 subfolder (or relatively speaking - its parent).

To better visualize:

```
Master folder
├ Parent folder 1
│ ├─ Subfolder A
│ │  ├─ File A
│ │  └─ File B
│ ├─ Subfolder B
│ │  ├─ File C
│ │  └─ File D
│ ├─ File E
│ └─ File F
.
. ... many folders more ...
.
└─ Parent folder 134
   ├─ Subfolder CS
   │  ├─ File AGF
   │  └─ File ARH
   ├─ File ROQ
   └─ File JGL
```

I need to move everything from any subfolders' content within its parent folder. As above, you can see that there may be some files already in the parent folder (e.g. Files E, F) and they should stay put.

Objective:

```
Master folder
├─ Parent folder 1
│  ├─ File A
│  ├─ File B
│  ├─ File C
│  ├─ File D
│  ├─ File E
│  └─ File F
├─ Parent folder 119
│  ├─ File AZA
│  ├─ File AZB
│  ├─ File AZC
│  └─ File AZD
... and so on
```

The challenge here is that there are over a hundred of these parent folders beneath the master folder and all have different names. The subfolders within the parent folders also have different names as well.

I've tried approaching this using `Get-ChildItem` then with a 'ForEach' attempting to assign the child item (i.e. folder) as a variable and then performing another `Get-ChildItem` recursive and moving all content to the parent, but I'm getting nowhere and if any movement, it seems to be referring back to C:\Windows\ folder.

Note [sorry, correction Not*] literal code, but the approach, I'm thinking of:

```
$master = "\\data\Master"
gci $master | foreach {
    $parent = $_
    gci ... | Move-Item -Destination $parent
}
```

Comment: You already have the right idea, although your code sample is a little incomplete (please always post a [mcve]). Your problem is that you set `$parent = $_` when you need `$parent` to be the full path of the folder. Change that line to `$parent = $_.FullName` and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I did try to make something for you. This will move everything from level2 folder to the level1 folder. Pls try it, and let me know how its working.

```
$master = "C:\Temp\Level0\"
Get-ChildItem $master | ForEach-Object {
    $dest = ($_.fullname)+"\"
    $Loc = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname)+"\*"
    Move-item -Path $Loc -Destination $dest
}
```

Comment: I've tried this at home (non-domain computer) and it seemed to work fine. However running this in office with a copy of some of the master folders content and placing on my own workstation it seems to fail and is pulling data from the root of the current drive to the parent folder. 
See the following code in the next comment.

Comment: Move-item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:6 char:5
+     Move-item -Path $Loc -Destination $dest
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Test\Master\...\FOLDER 1:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Move-item : Access to the path 'D:\OneNote' is denied.
At line:6 char:5
+     Move-item -Path $Loc -Destination $dest
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError:

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. It will however not move any files with the same filename to the parent folder if the filename has already been used.

```
$FilePath = Read-Host "Enter FilePath"
$FileSource = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath -Directory

foreach ($Directory in $FileSource)
{
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -File

    foreach ($File in $Files){
        Move-item -Path $File.Fullname -Destination $FilePath
    }
}
```

Hope that is of some use.

Comment: I've tried this, but doesn't work because the destination is the top level 'master' folder which houses all of the 'parent' subfolders. I need all files to be beneath the parent folder recursive, to be moved to the parent folder.